# Is there a way to set a track name like element in dash/mpd manifests?

Tags: http-live-streaming, mpeg-dash

at my .mpd file I have a lang="en" element, sadly in VideoJS this is not displayed as "English", instead it's displayed as is and the player simply shows "en" and "de" for example when it comes to language selection. Now I would like to know if there is a track_name like object that I can set in the mpd similar to what I can do in a HLS m3u8 playlist e.g.:

```
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="a-4",NAME="English",CHANNELS=2,AUTOSELECT="YES",DEFAULT="NO",LANGUAGE="en",URI="a-aac-en-mp4a.40.2_128000/master.m3u8"
```

NAME="English" is what gets displayed in VideoJS and LANGUAGE="en" indicated the actual real language. What's the equivalent in Dash/mpd here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Still wondering how Amazon is doing it: https://pop-dub-ww.cf.dash.row.aiv-cdn.net/dm/2$TAgS6n3bA2SdDDtG7XfoAFQmkKw~/1@164a9143e051f36330e9739ff2c0b2d3/fb80/46e0/afed/484b-b09f-404132c632d8/cec52a64-117c-450c-b896-14ba48ccc163_corrected.mpd?custom=true&amznDtid=AOAGZA014O5RE&encoding=segmentBase

Answer (score 1):

After some more searching I gave up finding the relevant information and checked onto the DASH-IF Slack channel where I finally got a response that could help me out with my problem.

In mpd manifests there is no direct attribute such as track or track_name or label... Instead, you can simply just add a Label element like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MPD xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011" id="master.mpd" minBufferTime="PT1.500S" type="static" mediaPresentationDuration="PT0H22M11.000S" profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-main:2011">
    <ProgramInformation moreInformationURL="https://strics.io">
        <Copyright>Blablablallala ...</Copyright>
    </ProgramInformation>
    <Period duration="PT0H22M11.000S">
        <AdaptationSet contentType="audio" mimeType="audio/mp4" segmentAlignment="true" lang="de" maxBandwidth="64000" minBandwidth="25600">
            <Label>Deutsch</Label>
            <Representation id="0_a" codecs="mp4a.40.5">
                <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:23003:3:audio_channel_configuration:2011" value="2"></AudioChannelConfiguration>
                <BaseURL>a-aac_he_v2-de-mp4a.40.5_64000/</BaseURL>
                <SegmentList timescale="1000" startNumber="0" duration="9000">
                    <Initialization sourceURL="init-a-aac_he_v2-de-mp4a.40.5_64000.m4s"></Initialization>
                    <SegmentURL media="f-0000.m4s" duration="9.002667"></SegmentURL>
                    <SegmentURL media="f-0001.m4s" duration="9.002667"></SegmentURL>
                    <SegmentURL media="f-0002.m4s" duration="9.002667"></SegmentURL>
...
```